# Transparently mapping a modified key (with xkb)

Tags: xkb

I'm trying to [simulate numeric keypad keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822857/how-to-emulate-integrated-numeric-keypad-cursor-keys-in-linux) on the main keyboard but am struggling with xkb.

How do I to convert a <LWIN> + <AD07> into a 'Left'?  (AKA Super + u)

It needs to play nice with Shift, Ctrl (and ideally Alt too).

The closest I came was:

```
    type "wkafk1" {
        modifiers = Shift+Super;
        map[Shift]= Level2;
        map[Super] = Level3;
        level_name[Level1] = "Base";
        level_name[Level2] = "Shift"; 
        level_name[Level3] = "Fn"; 
    };

...
    key <AD07> {
        type= "wkafk1",
        symbols[Group1]= [               u,               U, Left ]
    };
```

But Shift+Super+u isn't handled.

This one was close too:

```
    type "wkafk1" {
        modifiers = Shift+Super;
        map[Shift]= Level2;
        map[Super] = Level3;
        map[Shift+Super]=Level4;
        level_name[Level1] = "Base";
        level_name[Level2] = "Shift"; 
        level_name[Level3] = "Fn"; 
        level_name[Level4] = "Fn Shift";
    };
...
    key <AD07> {
        type= "wkafk1",
        symbols[Group1]= [               u,               U, Left, Shift+Left ]
    };
```

But it didn't compile because I don't know how to emit a modified symbol (Shift+Left is not allowed).

Do I need an 'interpret' statetment with action= RedirectKey(...) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to some [prior art](https://www.mail-archive.com/i18n@xfree86.org/msg01867.html), here are the steps:

1. Create a copy of current config:

```
xkbcomp $DISPLAY custom.xkb
```

2. Edit the resulting `custom.xkb`.
3. Find the end of section: `xkb_types` and add this:

```
     type "wkafk1" {
        modifiers = Shift+Super;
        map[Shift] = level2;
        map[Super] = level3;
        map[Super+Shift] = level3;
        level_name[Level1] = "Base";
        level_name[Level2] = "Caps";
        level_name[Level3] = "Arrows";
     };
```

4. Replace key definition `<AD07>` in section: `xkb_symbols` with this:

```
     key <AD07> {
         type= "wkafk1",
         symbols[Group1]= [ u, U, NoSymbol],
         actions[Group1]=[ NoAction(), NoAction(), RedirectKey(key=<LEFT>,clearmods=Super)]
     };
```

5. Compile and use customized config:

```
xkbcomp custom.xkb $DISPLAY
```

Note that this **works with Shift and Ctrl key** combinations.